# 12 hours clock with 3 slots for each hour

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, object

I am trying to generate an object from the user's two inputs `starts-at` and `duration`.

Basically, this object will display a 12 hours clock. Every hour has three slots 20 minutes each.

If they select `100` minutes from the duration the object should look like

```
{
    "1": [20, 40, 60],
    "2": [20, 40]
}
```

While the current output is

```
{
    "1": 40,
    "2": 40
}
```

Please advise.

```js
$(".btn-calculate").click(function () {
    var startsAt = Number($(".starts-at").val());
    var duration = Number($(".duration").val());

    var hours = Math.floor(duration / 60) + startsAt;
    var minutes = duration % 60;

    var occupiedSlots = {};

    while (hours >= 1) {
        occupiedSlots[hours] = minutes;
        --hours;
    }

    $("textarea").val(JSON.stringify(occupiedSlots, undefined, 4));
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: monospace;
}
select,
button {
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 400px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

Starts At
<select class="starts-at">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
</select>

Duration
<select class="duration">
    <option>20</option>
    <option>40</option>
    <option>60</option>
    <option>80</option>
    <option>100</option>
    <option>120</option>
    <option>140</option>
    <option>160</option>
    <option>180</option>
    <option>200</option>
    <option>220</option>
    <option>240</option>
</select>

<button class="btn-calculate">Calculate</button>

<textarea readonly></textarea>
```

Comment: What if the user selects a `starts-at` that is 1 but duration of `100`? Or a `starts_at` of 3. and a duration is 100, what should be the value for the key `3`?

Comment: 3 is the hour. So if they select 3 and 100, the output should be `{"3": [20, 40, 60], "4": [20, 40]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already pretty near to the correct solution. You have to create an array for each new hour and push the minutes into the array instead of setting the value:

```js
$(".btn-calculate").click(function () {
    const startsAt = Number($(".starts-at").val());
    const duration = Number($(".duration").val());

    const occupiedSlots = {};

    for (let time = 20; time <= duration; time += 20) {
        const hour = (Math.floor((time - 20) / 60) + startsAt - 1) % 12 + 1;
        if (!(hour in occupiedSlots)) occupiedSlots[hour] = [];
        occupiedSlots[hour].push((time - 20) % 60 + 20);
    }

    $("textarea").val(JSON.stringify(occupiedSlots, undefined, 4));
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: monospace;
}
select,
button {
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 400px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

Starts At
<select class="starts-at">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
</select>

Duration
<select class="duration">
    <option>20</option>
    <option>40</option>
    <option>60</option>
    <option>80</option>
    <option>100</option>
    <option>120</option>
    <option>140</option>
    <option>160</option>
    <option>180</option>
    <option>200</option>
    <option>220</option>
    <option>240</option>
</select>

<button class="btn-calculate">Calculate</button>

<textarea readonly></textarea>
```

Comment: You are Amazing! I understand that if I declare `occupiedSlots` outside the click event, I can keep track of all the slots that are in use. Which approach do you recommend to hide occupiedSlots from the dropdowns?

Comment: @Asher What does it mean _"to hide occupiedSlots from the dropdowns"_?

Comment: So for example after the first click the occupiedSlots are `{"1":[20,40,60],"2":[20,40]}`. I want to remove1 from start at the dropdown and 20, 40 from the duration dropdown as these slots are already in use. Makes sense?

Comment: @Asher This requires dynamic HTML. It gets even more complexity if duration options depend on the selected starts-at option. Single Page Application (SPA) frameworks solve this problem for you but it takes some time to learn it. You have to dynamically create the list of options and update it on button click.

Comment: I understand this is going to be complex. I can build the dynamic options. Do you think creating another object `freeSlots` which is `allSlots - occupiedSlots` to build the dropdowns is a good move? I will also check SPA.

Comment: @Asher _"Do you think creating another object freeSlots which is allSlots - occupiedSlots to build the dropdowns is a good move?"_ Probably it's a way to solve this problem.